# hyperref with breaklinks option + hypdvips give unexpected output

Tags: hyperref, hypdvips

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.4cm]{geometry} % to get margins which create a line break within the link
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypdvips}

\begin{document}

\subsection{something}
\label{spm:41}
\subsection{something}
\label{spm:43}
F{\o}lgende figur viser en skitse, der er set fra siden, af biografsalen,
som omtales i \autoref{spm:41}--\ref{spm:43}:

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Why is the entire text hyperlinked and not just `subsec-`, `tion 0.1`, and `0.2` and how do I fix this?

P.S. I compile via `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want `quadpoints=false`? Otherwise, `hypdvips` tries to set the link area to an entire rectangle so that it can create a single link, even when the link text breaks across lines. So, when a reference is split across lines, it ends up including the area before the reference starts and the area after the reference ends to create a single rectangle. At least, that's what I gather from the documentation. Setting this to false creates separate links on each line.

[image: falsify quadpoints]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.4cm]{geometry} % to get margins which create a line break within the link
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[quadpoints=false]{hypdvips}

\begin{document}

  \subsection{something}
  \label{spm:41}
  \subsection{something}
  \label{spm:43}
  F{\o}lgende figur viser en skitse, der er set fra siden, af biografsalen,
  som omtales i \autoref{spm:41}--\ref{spm:43}:

\end{document}
```